# When and where dummy.data.frame would be used?

Tags: machine-learning, r, data-mining

I am learning this [post](https://www.kaggle.com/himakund/tuning-svm-bringing-accuracy-from-62-to-98-8), in which, the author gives the piece of code:

```
outcome<-dataf1$outcome
dataf1$outcome<-NULL
datafd<-dummy.data.frame(dataf1)
hdata<-cbind(data,datafd,outcome)
head(str(hdata))
data<-hdata
```

Other parts are easy to understand though, what does this line: `dummy.data.frame(dataf1)` do?

I constructed a tiny dataset to figure this out:

```
title <- c('engineer','manager','sales','engineer','sales')
salary <- c(51000, 33700, 26800, 53700, 36800)
df = data.frame(title, salary)
df
dummy.data.frame(df)
```

Which produces:

```
  titleengineer titlemanager titlesales salary
1             1            0          0  51000
2             0            1          0  33700
3             0            0          1  26800
4             1            0          0  53700
5             0            0          1  36800
```

I cannot imagine what this is used for.

Answer (score 2):

The original df looks like:

```
     title salary
1 engineer  51000
2  manager  33700
3    sales  26800
4 engineer  53700
5    sales  36800
```

Using `dummy.data.frame(df)`, the character column "title" is recoded as "one-hot" (aka as dummy variable). Each column =1 if `title=TRUE` (or zero otherwise).

```
  titleengineer titlemanager titlesales salary
1             1            0          0  51000
2             0            1          0  33700
3             0            0          1  26800
4             1            0          0  53700
5             0            0          1  36800
```

An alternative encoding would be to use "title" as a factor with three levels
`df$title = as.factor(df$title)`.

However, in many cases "one hot" can be digested better by ML algorithms.

**Simple example:**

```
title <- c('engineer','manager','sales','engineer','sales')
salary <- c(51000, 33700, 26800, 53700, 36800)
df = data.frame(title, salary)
df

library(dummies)
df2 = dummy.data.frame(df)
df2
```

OLS model with "factor":

```
df$title = as.factor(df$title)
ols = lm(salary~., data=df)
summary(ols)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = salary ~ ., data = df)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5 
-1.350e+03  5.684e-14 -5.000e+03  1.350e+03  5.000e+03 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     52350       3662  14.295  0.00486 **
titlemanager   -18650       6343  -2.940  0.09882 . 
titlesales     -20550       5179  -3.968  0.05804 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5179 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8992,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7983 
F-statistic: 8.918 on 2 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.1008
```

OLS model with "dummies":

```
ols2 = lm(salary~titlemanager+titlesales, data=df2)
summary(ols2)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = salary ~ titlemanager + titlesales, data = df2)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5 
-1.350e+03  5.684e-14 -5.000e+03  1.350e+03  5.000e+03 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     52350       3662  14.295  0.00486 **
titlemanager   -18650       6343  -2.940  0.09882 . 
titlesales     -20550       5179  -3.968  0.05804 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5179 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8992,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7983 
F-statistic: 8.918 on 2 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.1008
```

**Summary:**

Results are the same. Dummies are a different representation of R's factors. Sometimes you need to pass content explicity as dummies. In this case `model.matrix()` often is useful. ([docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.0/topics/model.matrix))